# golang binary not running on mips

Tags: go, mips

I'm using Go 1.11.4 on Windows 10 and I want to compile code for a MIPS 74Kc processor (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9558) running Linux.  I compile with:

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips go build`

Get an executable, upload and run it and get:

`Illegal instruction`

Try again w/ `GOARCH=mipsle` and get:

`./hello_mipsle_linux: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("`

What am I missing?

Comment: We're you able to solve this? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: Yes.  See my answer below.  Simply add `GOMIPS=softfloat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My host doing the build had an FPU but the board does not.  Adding `GOMIPS=softfloat` fixed it:

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips GOMIPS=softfloat go build`

Comment: FYI: These MIPS binaries also run on Unifi AC access points! :D

Answer (score 1):

To list all possible MIPS architects available to your current build toolchain, use the `go tool` e.g.

```
$ go version

go version go1.12 darwin/amd64

$ go tool dist list | grep mips

linux/mips
linux/mips64
linux/mips64le
linux/mipsle
```

so probably one of the remaining `GOARCH` permutations you have not tried e.g. `mips64` or `mips64le`.

`uname -m` would help to determine your target system's machine architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue and it's solved by setting `GOARCH=mipsle`. This should work

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle GOMIPS=softfloat go build
```

My core is `MIPS 24KEc V5.0`, see my blog https://zyfdegh.github.io/post/202002-go-compile-for-mips/

If it's not OK, try these steps

1. Check the CPU architecture, Big-Endian or Little-Endian, by

```sh
$ lscpu | grep "Byte Order"
```

cat `/proc/cpuinfo` would also be helpful.

2. Check kernel info, mips or mips64, for me it's mips (32)

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux OpenWrt 4.14.151 #0 Tue Nov 5 14:12:18 2019 mips GNU/Linux
```

3. If it's Little-Endian, set `GOARCH=mipsle`, if it's 64bit Little-Endian, set set `GOARCH=mips64le`

Another related question [Writing and Compiling Program For OpenWrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878437/writing-and-compiling-program-for-openwrt/60161561#60161561) hope it helps.