# Writing and Compiling Program For OpenWrt

Tags: linux, embedded, cross-compiling, openwrt

I have a embedded device with MIPS arch working under OpenWRT

> system type: MediaTek MT7628AN ver:1 eco:2
>   machine: WRTnode2P 
>   processor: 0
>   cpu model: MIPS 24KEc V5.5

I want to compile compile a small program in C through my computer (ubuntu)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("HelloWorld");
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it I use mips-linux-gnu-gcc command

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -march=24kec -mabi=32 hello.c -o hello
```

I send hello program to my device and make a chmod 755

```
chmod 755 hello
```

When I try to execute it I have an error

```
root@openWrt:/www# ./hello
./hello: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
```

I don't understand what's going on, I tried some others command to compile it like with argument: -EB or -EL or not, -static or not, -mabi=32 and not, but I have same problem.

Anyone to help me?

Thanks

[UPDATE]

I send a file command to existing file and this is result

```
fw3: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

so I compile my program with this command

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -march=24kec -mips32r2  -mips16   hello.c -o hello
```

now I have this file command result

```
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld., for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=cd12319441c530606d52d96478719b06a7b215a7, not stripped
```

Now I read ELF of my remote program

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       1
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x402c40
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          78592 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x74001005, noreorder, cpic, o32, mips16, mips32r2
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         10
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         31
  Section header string table index: 30
```

and this my hello program readelf command

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x4005c0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6700 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x74001007, noreorder, pic, cpic, o32, mips16, mips32r2
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         11
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         33
  Section header string table index: 30
```

There is two difference ABI version and in flags there is pic

If I try to launch my hello program I have this error

```
hello: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I try to add -static argument but I have this error when I launch my hello program

```
Illegal instruction
```

I'm always stuck with this problem.

Comment: are you trying to run you program on a mips arch?

Comment: Yes my device running under mips arch

Comment: can you show the result of `file ./hello` and `ldd ./hello` please?

Comment: Have u resolved the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try build with mipsle

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle GOMIPS=softfloat go build
```

I have a similar issue and fixed it by setting architect to ***mipsle***. I'm using Go to build binary for linux/mips on this device,

```sh
system type     : MediaTek MT7620A ver:2 eco:6
cpu model       : MIPS 24KEc V5.0
isa             : mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2
ASEs implemented    : mips16 dsp
```

It fails on the first time,

```sh
macbook:# cat main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello, mips")
}

#### Setting GOARCH=mips

macbook:# GOOS=linux GOARCH=mips GOMIPS=softfloat go build -o hello-mips

openwrt:# ./hello-mips
./hello-mips: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Then I realized the CPU arch is [Little-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), not the default Big-Endian. So I changed the build parameter and it successes now.

```sh
#### Setting GOARCH=mipsle

macbook:# GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle GOMIPS=softfloat go build -o hello
openwrt:# ./hello
hello, mips
```

Your CPU model is same as mine and only differs in the revision `MIPS 24KEc V5.5`, it must also be mipsle (mipsel). Hope it helps.